# JQuery com Ajax para atualizar mesma página PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma página chamada **formulario.php** que tem o seguinte código:

```
if(isset($_POST['date'])){
            $date = ($_POST['date']);
    echo "Data: ".$date;
}
```

A página também tem um formulário com um datepicker do JQuery:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"/>
</form>
```

E, também, o código JS:

```
$(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    minDate: 0, 
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {date : dateText},
            success: function(resp){
                if(false !== resp){
                    alert(dateText);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
  });
```

Quando eu seleciono a data no datepicker, o alert do javascript funciona sem problemas. Mesmo assim, o **isset** do PHP sempre retorna falso. Ou seja, por algum motivo o Ajax não está recarregando a página com o valor do `$_POST`. Existe algum problema no código acima ou algum método mas eficaz de fazer essa passagem de variável?

O resultado da variável **resp** é:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">




    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Dashboard I Admin Panel</title>






    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.css" />

    <!-- Load jQuery JS -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <!-- Load jQuery UI Main JS  -->
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- Load SCRIPT.JS which will create datepicker for input field  -->


        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    minDate: 0, 
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {date : dateText},
            success: function(resp){
                alert(resp);

            }
        });
    }
});
  });

</script>

</head>


<body>
    <span id="hoverdata"></span>
    <header id="header">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="site_title"><a href="index.html">Website Admin</a></h1>
            <h2 class="section_title">Dashboard</h2><div class="btn_view_site"><a href="http://www.medialoot.com">View Site</a></div>
        </hgroup>
    </header> <!-- end of header bar -->

    <section id="secondary_bar">
        <div class="user">
            <p>John Doe (<a href="#">3 Messages</a>)</p>
            <!-- <a class="logout_user" href="#" title="Logout">Logout</a> -->
        </div>
        <div class="breadcrumbs_container">
            <article class="breadcrumbs"><a href="index.html">Website Admin</a> <div class="breadcrumb_divider"></div> <a class="current">Dashboard</a></article>
        </div>
    </section><!-- end of secondary bar -->

    <aside id="sidebar" class="column">

        <form class="quick_search">

            <input type="text" value="Quick Search" onfocus="if(!this._haschanged){this.value=''};this._haschanged=true;">

        </form>

        <hr/>

        <h3>Content</h3>

        <ul class="toggle">

            <li class="icn_new_article"><a href="#">New Article</a></li>

            <li class="icn_edit_article"><a href="#">Edit Articles</a></li>

            <li class="icn_categories"><a href="#">Categories</a></li>

            <li class="icn_tags"><a href="#">Tags</a></li>

        </ul>

        <h3>Módulos de Avaliação</h3>

        <ul class="toggle">

            <li class="stats_graph"><a href="#">New Article</a></li>

            <li class="icn_edit_article"><a href="#">Edit Articles</a></li>

            <li class="icn_categories"><a href="#">Categories</a></li>

            <li class="icn_tags"><a href="#">Tags</a></li>

        </ul>

        <h3>Users</h3>

        <ul class="toggle">

            <li class="icn_add_user"><a href="#">Add New User</a></li>

            <li class="icn_view_users"><a href="#">View Users</a></li>

            <li class="icn_profile"><a href="#">Your Profile</a></li>

        </ul>

        <h3>Media</h3>

        <ul class="toggle">

            <li class="icn_folder"><a href="#">File Manager</a></li>

            <li class="icn_photo"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>

            <li class="icn_audio"><a href="#">Audio</a></li>

            <li class="icn_video"><a href="#">Video</a></li>

        </ul>

        <h3>Admin</h3>

        <ul class="toggle">

            <li class="icn_settings"><a href="#">Options</a></li>

            <li class="icn_security"><a href="#">Security</a></li>

            <li class="icn_jump_back"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>

        </ul>



        <footer>

            <hr />

            <p><strong>Copyright &copy; 2011 Website Admin</strong></p>

            <p>Theme by <a href="http://www.medialoot.com">MediaLoot</a></p>

        </footer>

    </aside><!-- end of sidebar -->Array
(
    [date] => 03/24/2016
)
Data: <span id='a-data'>03/24/2016</span>   
    <section id="main" class="column">
        <form id="myform" name="myform">
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"/>
            <input type="button" id="submitMe">
        </form>

        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </section>


</body>

</html>
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Acho que você não está mostrando código suficiente pra reproduzir o problema, mas eu trocaria o echo por `echo "Data: <span id='a-data'>". $date . "</span>";` e manipulava o span com o resultado.

Comment: já passar o parâmetro por `GET` para ver se vai? As vezes pode ser algum problema na hora de enviar por `POST`

Comment: No inicio do seu PHP da um print_r($_POST) e no success do ajax antes do "if" coloca console.log(resp) para ver no console do chrome o que está realmente retornando.

Comment: @brasofilo o restante do código é puro html, não sei se influenciaria neste problema, mas posso atualizar a pergunta com ele. Quanto a <span>, não entendi muito bem qual a finalidade dele.

Comment: @BrumazziD.B. GET ou POST acontece a mesma coisa, sem resultado em nenhum dos dois.

Comment: @AndréVicente Atualizei a pergunta com o resultado do resp. Aparentemente no resp ele processa o php corretamente.

Comment: Está retornando correto, o ajax pega tudo o que tem na página. Se vc tem um form na página e códigos html vai vir tudo mesmo. Está até trazendo o print_r com o array date com a data que vc escolheu. Seria melhor se vc fizesse uma página php a parte apenas para trabalhar com seu form, crie uma página, por exemplo "form.php" e coloque na chamada do ajax url: "form.php", ai vc vai conseguir trabalhar com a data corretamente